# Image inside of div not centering

Tags: css, html, centering

I can't seem to centre an image inside of a div. 
the image not centered is the "quotimg" which is inside of the div quotejd which is inside of div head.

Currently learning some css and html (not supposed to use html5 elements)

HTML

```
<div class="head">

   <div class="quotejd">

      <img id="quoteimg" src="pictures/quotes/jd.png">

      <p id="quote">“The only creatures that are evolved enough to convey pure love<br> are dogs and infants.”</p>

</div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.Head {
background-image: url('pictures/dogwallpaper1.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
height: 550;
text-align: center;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.quotejd {
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;

}

 #quoteimg {
width: 5em;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
display: block;
float: none;
}

#quote {
font-size: 1.8em;
line-height: 1em;
margin: 0 auto;
text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(57,57,57,1);
font-family: 'Nixie One', cursive;
text-align: center;
color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: Works fine - http://jsfiddle.net/bjSZ5/

Comment: @DSG doesn't seem to work http://i.imgur.com/fKH158t.png, any other things should influence that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tripped me up when I was learning CSS too. Try setting the div surrounding your image (with the class .quotejd) to a set width (i.e. width:960px). The auto value of margin doesn't know how to center it otherwise.

Comment: I've tried setting the divs - "quotedj" and "head"'s width to 79em which didn't work as well. This is what worked in the meanwhile: padding the "quotejd" div to 30px but it's not really centered

Comment: Yeah, padding isn't going to be the way to center it. Do you want your head section to fill the whole page? I might set the .head width to 100% and then set the inner div ".quotejd" to something like 75%. Every time you use margin:0 auto, you need to specify your width (and I tend to use percentages to test it). Maybe like Ankit said above, a screenshot of what you're trying to do would help.

Comment: i.imgur.com/fKH158t.png , I would like it to stay around 79em.

Comment: Okay, I see. Have you tried to set the .head to the full width of the section as well as .quotejd to the width of 79em? Is it still not working?

Comment: Okay, take a look at this code: http://jsfiddle.net/shudson4/Ag4Dy/ Make sure you have your class lowercase in your CSS and you have to use width:79em in both the .head and .quotejd divs.